# How do I prevent the parens and quotations being printed when printing elements from a list?

Tags: python, printing

```
def winners(finish_order, teams):
    return finish_order[0], 'and', teams[finish_order[0]], 'won the race!'

print(winners(['Green', 'Zelda', 'Frog'], {'Zelda':'Midna', 'Frog':'Frogette', 'Green':'Red'}))
```

So running the code above prints **('Green', 'and', 'Red', 'won the race!')**.
How do I print **Green and Red won the race!** instead? Basically, I want to print elements from the list without the extra parentheses and quotations, when using them in a sentence.

Comment: `print("%s and %s won the race!" % (finish_order[0], teams[finish_order[0]]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return formatted string, not tuple:

```
def winners(finish_order, teams):
    return '{} and {} won the race!'.format(finish_order[0], teams[finish_order[0]])

print(winners(['Green', 'Zelda', 'Frog'], {'Zelda':'Midna', 'Frog':'Frogette', 'Green':'Red'}))
```

Prints:

```
Green and Red won the race!
```